# jQuery addClass to a div if another div has a class

Tags: jquery

I am looking to ad a class to the trigger div ONLY IF the panel div is open. Can;t quite crack it.

Basically: open panel = "active" class added to it's trigger

I threw this fiddle together to make life easier: http://jsfiddle.net/markthelefty/NLzz4/

Thanks!

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // add initial action- first panel
        $(".trigger:first").bind("click",function(){
                $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
            })
        $(".panel").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("close");
            $(this).css("display","none");
        })
        $(".panel:first").removeClass("close");
        $(".panel:first").addClass("open");
        $(".panel:first").css("display","block");
        var lastid=$(".trigger:last").attr("id");
        $(".next").click(function(){
            var parid=$(this).parent().attr("id");
            var first=0;
            $(this).parent().prev().unbind("click");
            $(this).parent().prev().bind("click",function(){
                $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
            })
            var nextid=$(this).parent().next().attr("id");

            if (nextid==lastid)
            {
            $(this).parent().next().unbind("click");
                $(this).parent().next().bind("click",function(){
                    $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
                })
            }
            $(".close").each(function(){
                var id=$(this).attr("id");
                if(id>parid && first==0) {
                    $(this).removeClass("close");
                    $(this).addClass("open");
                    first=1;

                    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            }
            })
            $(this).parent().removeClass("open");
            $(this).parent().addClass("close");
            $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow");

        })
    })
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="trigger-1" class="trigger">
        <h1>Panel One Trigger (Entire black area)</h1>
    </div><!--/trgger-1-->

    <div id="panel-1" class="panel">
        <p>Or sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis faucibus quam, sit amet ornare risus dignissim vitae. Praesent accumsan quam nec velit viverra vitae faucibus mi lacinia. Donec at leo eget massa lobortis gravida. Phasellus eu ligula non sem scelerisque sodales sit amet sed metus. </p>
        <a href="#" class="next">NEXT STEP ></a>
    </div><!--/panel-1-->



    <div id="trigger-2" class="trigger">
        <h1>Panel Two Trigger (Entire black area)</h1>
    </div><!--/trgger-2-->

    <div id="panel-2" class="panel">
        <p>Or sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis faucibus quam, sit amet ornare risus dignissim vitae. Praesent accumsan quam nec velit viverra vitae faucibus mi lacinia. Donec at leo eget massa lobortis gravida. Phasellus eu ligula non sem scelerisque sodales sit amet sed metus. </p>
        <a href="#" class="next">NEXT STEP ></a>
    </div><!--/panel-2-->



    <div id="trigger-3" class="trigger">
        <h1>Panel Three Trigger (Entire black area)</h1>
    </div><!--/trgger-3-->

    <div id="panel-3" class="panel">
        <p>Or sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis faucibus quam, sit amet ornare risus dignissim vitae. Praesent accumsan quam nec velit viverra vitae faucibus mi lacinia. Donec at leo eget massa lobortis gravida. Phasellus eu ligula non sem scelerisque sodales sit amet sed metus. </p>
        <a href="#" class="submit">SUBMIT ></a>
    </div><!--/panel-3-->
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could reduce this significantly to illustrate the problem without everything else.

Comment: Hi Grant-You are probably right but I am a bit of a jQuery nOOb so I wanted you to be able to see the whole piece. Sorry if it's a bit overkill.

Comment: All fair points. Simply put I tried everything I could think of and was at my wits end and was hoping to get a second set of eyes on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$('div.panel').slideUp();

$('div.trigger').on("click",function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("open"))
    {
       $('div.panel').slideUp();
       $('div.trigger').removeClass("open");
       $(this).next("div").slideDown();
       $(this).addClass("open");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).next('div').slideUp();
        $('div.trigger').removeClass("open");
        $('div.panel').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLzz4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Not able to get your code but this might help you moving forward:

```
// If panel div has class open
if ($(".panel").hasClass("open")) {

    // Then add class close to trigger div
    $(".trigger").addClass("close");
}
```